# How do I set my workspace enviornment variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The top of the file I am working on has the following code:

```
sys.path.append(os.environ['WORKSPACE'])
```

When I run pytest, I receive the following error:

```
(file name):3: in <module>
    sys.path.append(os.environ['WORKSPACE'])
/usr/lib64/python3.6/os.py:669: in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
E   KeyError: 'WORKSPACE'
```

I am trying to set my Python path to fix it but it's not solving the issue. Is this because I'm working in a virtual environment? How can I set the WORKSPACE variable?

Comment: "I am trying to set my Python path to fix it but it's not solving the issue." Well, yes, because `PYTHONPATH` isn't the missing environment variable; `WORKSPACE` is. "How can I set the WORKSPACE variable?" The same way that you set any other *environment variable*. The ways to do this from your operating system depends on the operating system; if this is the actual question, then you have a "how do I use my computer?" question and not a programming question, and should try https://superuser.com (or better yet, an Internet search) instead.

Comment: If you want to do it from within Python, then you can simply assign to the appropriate key in `os.environ`, [as explained in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) - which you [should have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) looked up before asking.

Answer (score 1):

This command os.environ['WORKSPACE'] search in system variables you can check it:
windows (cmd)

> set

Linux (bash)

> printenv

you can set it:

windows (cmd)

> setx WORKSPACE "c:\Users\"

linux (bash)

> export WORKSPACE=/usr